# Button click call to node js function failing

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to make a button that makes a call to the node js server function route `getMentions`, but it's not being invoked

This is my button in `index.html`:

```
<button action="/getMentions" class="btn" id="btn1">Show Mentions</button>
```

and these are my functions in `index.js`:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index.html');});

router.get('/getMentions', function (req, res) {
    console.log("got to GET MENTIONS!");
    performRequest();});
```

The first route hits fine and the html is rendered, so then why doesn't the second one work? I think it's something with my configuration maybe. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in adv!

Comment: because.... you didn't do anything that would send a request back to the server. Where did you read about giving an `action` attribute to a button?

Comment: @KevinB .. I clicked the button though, and the 'action' should take care of it right?

Comment: no? what is an action attribute on a button supposed to do? nothing as far as I know. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Answer (score 1):

`<button>` elements do not have `action` attribute. Probably, what you are looking for is the [`formaction`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-fs-formaction) attribute that is used for overriding the `action` property of a parent `form` element.

Comment: Oh you're right! That's what I was probably forgetting. But how can I do the same with just a button? `href` or `onclick` attributes won't work either

Comment: `formaction` is an attribute of `button` elements, so you replace the `action` with `formaction` (you should, of course, have a `form` element). Also note that for testing a route you don't have to click  a button, you can type the url in your browser's address bar and hit the enter key.  Please note that your `/getMentions` doesn't seem to send a response and server will time out waiting for the request.